# Change value conditionally (2 conditions) in a data frame and avoid loops in R

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, data.table, conditional-statements

I have a situation where I currently use very time-consuming loops.

My datasets :
SPECIE (3 columns data.frame) ;
WORLD (3 columns matrix)

In **SPECIE**, I have 3 variables : **LAT, LON, OCC** (numeric)
OCC is always > 0. SPECIE contains the position where the specie was found, and the number of time it was found (in OCC).
Length of SPECIE is often around 3000.

In WORLD, I have all the latitudes and longitudes of the world (grid -180 to 180, -90 to 90, res 0.5)
So, in **WORLD**, I have : **LAT, LON, OCC**
OCC is often 0. Length of WORLD is 259200 (180 * 2 * 360 * 2) x 3columns

My goal : modify OCC in world where the specie was found. At the end, I have all the latitudes/longitudes of the world, plus the information if the specie was found or not at a precise lat/lon couple.

Currently, I do :

```
for(j in 1:259200)
{
for(k in 1:length(SPECIE$OCC))
{

if((SPECIE$LON[k] == WORLD[j,1]) & (SPECIE$LAT[k] == WORLD[j,2]))
{
WORLD[j,3] <- SPECIE$OCC[k]
}

}
}
```

I looked for a solution without the loops (it takes hours), but didn't find something working.

Heads:

```
> head(WORLD)
    [,1]      [,2]   [,3]
[1,] -179.75 -89.75    0
[2,] -179.75 -89.25    0
[3,] -179.75 -88.75    0
[4,] -179.75 -88.25    0

> head(SPECIE)
    LON   LAT     OCC
1 -89.75 24.75       1
2 -89.75 25.25       1
3 -89.75 25.75       6
4 -89.75 26.25      45
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amazing `data.table` package is your friend here, it will take care of this job in the blink of an eye.

Since you did not supply data, I simulated some, such that all values of LAT and LON in SPECIE are contained within the same coordinates in WORLD, but there are also values in WORLD that are not contained in SPECIE.  I made up very regular values for LAT and LON but with the real data, it should work in the same way.

```
require(data.table)

# set lengths for example
nSPECIE <- 5
nWORLD <- 10

# simulate the SPECIE data, from data.frame to data.table
SPECIE <- data.frame(LAT = 1:nSPECIE,
                     LON = 1:nSPECIE,
                     OCC_specie = 1:nSPECIE)
SPECIE <- as.data.table(SPECIE)

# simulate the WORLD data, from matrix to data.table
WORLD <- matrix(c(1:nWORLD,
                  1:nWORLD,
                  rpois(nWORLD, 1)),
                ncol = 3,
                dimnames = list(NULL, c("LAT", "LON", "OCC_world")))
WORLD <- as.data.table(WORLD)

# merge
setkey(SPECIE, LAT, LON)
setkey(WORLD, LAT, LON)
WORLD_modified <- SPECIE[WORLD]
##     LAT LON OCC_specie OCC_world
##  1:   1   1          1         0
##  2:   2   2          2         2
##  3:   3   3          3         2
##  4:   4   4          4         0
##  5:   5   5          5         0
##  6:   6   6         NA         1
##  7:   7   7         NA         0
##  8:   8   8         NA         2
##  9:   9   9         NA         2
## 10:  10  10         NA         3
```

As you can see, the OCC value from SPECIE is now matched, and the locations in WORLD that had no corresponding record in SPECIE are given an NA value for the OCC column from SPECIE.

Just to show you how **ridiculously fast** this is, you can up the parameters:

```
# with original sizes
nSPECIE <- 3000
nWORLD <- 259000
SPECIE <- data.frame(LAT = 1:nSPECIE,
                     LON = 1:nSPECIE,
                     OCC_specie = 1:nSPECIE)
SPECIE <- as.data.table(SPECIE)
WORLD <- matrix(c(1:nWORLD,
                  1:nWORLD,
                  rpois(nWORLD, 1)),
                ncol = 3,
                dimnames = list(NULL, c("LAT", "LON", "OCC_world")))
WORLD <- as.data.table(WORLD)
setkey(SPECIE, LAT, LON)
setkey(WORLD, LAT, LON)
system.time(WORLD_modified <- SPECIE[WORLD])
##    user  system elapsed 
##   0.003   0.000   0.004
```

Read the `data.table` [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf) and [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf), it is time very well invested if you need to match tables.  The excellent `dplyr` package also makes use of this but I prefer straight up `data.table` for jobs like this.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted some example data, but try this:

```
world.df <- as.data.frame(world)
names(world) <- names(specie)
matches <- which(world.df$lat %in% specie$lat & world.df$lon %in% specie$lon)
world.df$occ[matches] <- merge(specie, world.df, by=c('lat', 'lon'))$occ.x
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited my post to add example data. I still have a problem with your solution, it doesn't work. I have `length(SPECIE$OCC)` = 9434, and `length(matches)` = 19488, which can't be (they logically have to be equal)

Comment: You may have to switch the order surround the `%in%` operator then.